# How can artificial gravity hold the water in swimming pool?

Tags: gravity, water

I was watching **Passengers (2016)**. In this movie, a swimming pool exists in the space station. In middle of the movie, Artificial Gravity is turned off and the water rises, with the swimmer suffocating as they try to get out of the water.

Suddenly Artificial Gravity turned itself on again and the swimmer survives.

[A clip of this scene is found on YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uP0_3MstCAA)

However, water is an anti-ferromagnetic material - it can't attract to magnetic bodies.

How then, can artificial gravity hold the water in swimming pool?

My question is totally different from this [question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/how-would-water-waves-behave-in-partial-gravity).

Comment: The magical nature of "Artificial Gravity" makes this hard to answer. Water held in place by centrifugal force will come back down in a spinning station because it effectively has an outward velocity when it's sitting in the bottom of the pool.

Comment: The artificial gravity in that movie is not consistent, as has been pointed out on Quora: https://www.quora.com/In-the-film-Passengers-artificial-gravity-seems-to-be-generated-by-rotation-But-then-why-would-it-stop-working-suddenly. Unfortunately, this means the question is not clear enough to answer here.

Comment: Probably, this question would get better answers in Wordbuilding SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Artificial gravity" should act like gravity. So just as gravity has a direction on earth and holds water in a pool, so should  "artificial gravity" hold water in a pool on a space station with  "artificial gravity." Notice that bubbles rise in the space station pool just as they would on earth.

If gravity were loss on a space station with a pool, then the surface tension of the water would want to pull the water into a sphere.

I'll also point out that water is an anti-ferromagnetic material in earth swimming pools, and gravity works just fine. So using magnetic boots on a steel deck is very different that having gravity which would work with an aluminum deck.